# Yii2 How can i use save() with this array?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-model

I have a problem with my code. I want to clone a string and into this string, there are three data. Each parameter is a different table of the DB.
When I run the code, Yii2 say error:

> Call to a member function save() on an array

this is in my controller:

```
public function actionClone($id)
{   
    $clone = Helper::get_clone_offer($id);
    if ($clone->save()) Helper::add_history(null, null, $id, '', 
    'Clone', 'Done', 0, 0, 'Offer', 1, 0, '');
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

this is in my Helper:

```
public static function get_clone_offer($id)
{

    $offer = Offers::findOne($id);
    $product = Helper::get_product_name($offer->id);
    $accessory = Helper::get_offer_product_accessories($offer->id);
    $clone = [$offer,$product,$accessory];
    $clone[0]->parent_id = $clone[0]->id; 
    $clone[0]->id += 1000 ;
    return $clone;
}
```

I'm new in Yii2 and `php`.
Thank you for help.

Comment: $clone is an array - why do you expect it to have a "save" method?

Comment: Thx Patrick I've see my error

Answer (score 0):

You havent explained what you are actually trying to achieve, but for the error that is throwing is a definite thing as the `$clone` you are returning from the `get_clone_offer()` function is not expected to have a `save()` method as it is an array.

You should try calling `$clone[0]->save()` if you are trying to save the `$offer` model what I can guess you are trying to do because you are setting the `Offer` model `id` to the `parent_id` field in the function `get_clone_offer()` and $clone is an array of models, and calling

- `$clone[0]->save()` will save the `Offer` model
- `$clone[1]->save()` will save the `Product` model
- `$clone[2]->save()` will save the `ProductAccessories` model

Moreover you should add the methods `get_product_name`, `get_offer_product_accessories` in the respective models rather than creating the Helper methods.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and help, I'm new and I still have not understood well how it works

Comment: you should go through the documentation to understand it thoroughly it takes time to learn dont worry , the `$clone` is an array of models thats why you should select the model first by using the `index` and then call the `save()` method. hope it helps @niksolaz